# How to set Email Recipients in UIActivityViewController In Swift. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a choice to my UIActivityViewController to allow my users to send an email to every single one of their contacts. How can I  assign email addresses to the recipient value of a UIActivityViewController's email sharing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible with `UIActivityViewController`. Recipients can be added only in `MFMailComposeViewController`. So you should try this instead of `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prefill this view controller. It is usually used for sharing and the user choses themselves, who they want to email.

You have to use `MFMailComposeViewController` for custom email prefilling.